# Bootstrap Nav Bar overriding color works in JSFiddle but still plain gray in the code i'm working on

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks to @DoctorDerp for answering my earlier question...that lead me to making the CSS changes to the nav bar. 
What I wanted to do was change the color of the nav bar.

For example, I put the code through jsFiddle: [Sample of Nav Bar color change](http://jsfiddle.net/M9MDX/)

```
/* --- Style --- */

.navbar-nav > li > a {
padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important;
}

.navbar {
    min-height:32px !important;
}

.navbar-default {
background-color: #1c1c1c;
border-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #ffffff;
}   
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
}
```

(The rest of the CSS is in the jsFiddle)

The color here is very simple. Black bar and grey hover color.
It works on the jsFiddle page. 
But when I bring in the CSS into the code that I'm working on the nav bar is still grey. The background should be gray but not the nav bar.

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing to override the colors?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same markup as in your other question, that inline style on that on your topmost div will be inherited by all of the child elements.

Two options:

1) Either remove that inline style and make it a class.

2) Add an important flag.

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #1C1C1C !important; /*this should do the trick I believe*/
    border-color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: I tried that already. I thought it would have been the issue too. THanks for the advice though.

Comment: THanks Kyle! That did it. Forgot that overriding that 'important' needs to be there. It's kind of a pain in the butt ... but hey...it works. Thanks for all the help!